# Memory Management with UIPopoverController

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uipopovercontroller

If I declare a UIPopoverController with the retain property, release is in the dealloc method, and assign the property to nil in my viewDidUnload method, can I use this one popover for multiple buttons?  Like I have two buttons where I can present the popover, both with there two different content views.  It seems to work, but I just didn't know if this was "good" practice, if there are memory problems by doing this, or if it's better to have a popover property for each popover i plan on showing?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating a new popovercontroller for each one or is it the same instance... I was wondering this too... But since uIPopovercontroller does not allow to initialize it without a content view controller.. my instinct is to create one for each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reusing it should be absolutely fine.

As long as you release the old one if you are going to display a new one it won't leak.